# I can't fetch cursor in python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I am using postgresql function and calling from python. but I can't fetch cursor.

this is my postgresql function.

```
  CREATE LANGUAGE plpgsql;
        create or replace FUNCTION getPerson() returns REFCURSOR
           AS $$
        DECLARE
        p_cursor refcursor;   
        BEGIN
           open p_cursor FOR
           select m.name AS name, m.surname AS surname from person m;
           RETURN p_cursor;
        END; $$
        LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

this is my python function

```
 import psycopg2    
    try:
       conn = psycopg2.connect(database="dt", user = "us", password = "pass", host = "127.0.0.1", port = "5432")

       cur = conn.cursor()
       res = cur.callproc('getPerson')
       result = cur.fetchall()

       for row in result:
           print "printed row"
           print row   

       conn.commit()
       cur.close()
       conn.close()  

    except:     
        print "error"
```

RESULT:

```
printed row
('<unnamed portal 1>',)
```

Comment: You need to make additional step: create yet another cursor for `fetch all from "<unnamed portal 1>"` (use name returned by function) and then fetch your data from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Abelisto mentionned, when calling a procedure, you need to get cursor's name first. With psycopg2 it's:

```
res = cur.callproc('getPerson')
row = cur.fetchone()
```

then proceed with another FETCH query:

```
cur.execute(f'FETCH ALL IN "{row[0]}"') #Note: python 3.6
results = cur.fetchall()
```

Full code:

```
import psycopg2    
try:
   conn = psycopg2.connect(database="dt", user = "us", password = "pass", host = "127.0.0.1", port = "5432")
   cur = conn.cursor()

   res = cur.callproc('getPerson')
   row = cur.fetchone()

   cur.execute(f'FETCH ALL IN "{row[0]}"')
   results = cur.fetchall()

   for row in results:
       print row   

   cur.close()

except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    print(error)
finally:
    if conn is not None:
        conn.close()
        print('Database connection closed.')
```